# how to find running procedure name

Tags: oracle, plsql

help to solve issue related session monitoring.
select sql_id,
(select o.owner || '.' || o.OBJECT_NAME
from dba_objects o
where o.OBJECT_ID = cu) object,
'LINE' ||'-' || program_line# line
from v$sql

Answer (score 0):

Typically (if your user has relevant authority and you run a client like sqldeveloper, for example) you can do a session monitor by going to Tools > Session Monitor to view all open sessions.

Otherwise, you could use this very basic i have used many, many times to find open sessions in your DB running by the user you're logged into (if this is relevant);

```html
select 
  oracle_username,
  os_user_name,
  locked_mode,
  object_name,
  object_type,
  sysdate,
  a.session_id,
  a.process,
  c.machine,
  c.program,
  c.module,
  c.action,
  c.logon_time,
  c.last_call_et,
  c.state
from 
  v$locked_object a,dba_objects b, v$session c
where 
  a.object_id = b.object_id
  and C.sid = a.SESSION_ID 
  and ORACLE_USERNAME = user
order by OBJECT_NAME, ORACLE_USERNAME;
```

This SQL can be adjusted to your needs. Just remember that you can't view sessions if your user doesn't have the right permissions.

this is the best I could gather from your question, can you be more specific...?